# Understanding Hierarchy of the $scope in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

When I create a object and navigate through the _proto__ property of it I get to know that it has been inherited from Object

[image]

Now when I create a new object and inherit the obj object, then I get the inheritance structure like this
[image]

Here i can understand that the object obj1 is being inherited from the object obj and the object obj is being inherited from the object Object, which is the global object.

Now my question is, when i debug in my console i get both obj and obj1 as Object but the when i debug the $scope of angularJS i get something like this

[image]

Why is the $scope returning b instead of Object which can be seen in all the two images above, what is so different in angularJS, am i missing something.

**UPDATE 1**

when I make a object of the constructor in javascript I get the function name in the constructor as shown in the image below

[image]

But in the case of the $scope i see no constructor function, why is that? am i missing something, please let me know

Comment: @Maximus do you know the answer for my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're debugging minified application.

`$scope` is an instance of [internal `Scope` or `ChildScope` class](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.8/src/ng/rootScope.js#L240-L250).

In minified Angular bundle the class is called something like `b`.

Comment: There's no `constructor` because it is is deeper on the prototype chain. You will see it when logging `$scope.constructor`.

Answer (score 1):

When you inspect an object in console, it is referenced by this object's class name, for example:

```
function Scope() {}
var s = new Scope();
```

[image]

In your case, instead of `function Scope() {}`, in the minified version the code looks like this  `function b() {}` and `new b()` is used instead of `new Scope()`